# Ionic 4 change ion-tab-button with custom icon

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to change `ion-icon` with custom src after `ion-tab-button` is clicked

What I have tried, using (click) event to trigger function and change the [src]="..." inside the ion-icon

Is there any proper way to change this hackish style?

HTML:

```
 <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="news/home" (click)="changeNewsIcon()">
      <ion-icon [src]="newsIcon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="tab-title">News</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="user" (click)="changeSearchIcon()">
      <ion-icon [src]="searchIcon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="tab-title">Search</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="networking" (click)="changeNetworkIcon()">
      <ion-icon [src]="notiIcon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="tab-title">Networking</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="chat" (click)="changeChatIcon()">
      <ion-icon [src]="chatIcon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="tab-title">Chat</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="profile" (click)="changeProfIcon()">
      <ion-icon [src]="profIcon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="tab-title">Profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

TS :

```
newsIcon = './assets/tabs/home.svg';
searchIcon = './assets/tabs/search.svg';
notiIcon = './assets/tabs/group.svg';
chatIcon = './assets/tabs/chat.svg';
profIcon = './assets/tabs/user.svg';

changeNewsIcon(): void {    
  // change news icon
  this.newsIcon = './assets/tabs/clicked-home.svg';

  // reset others icon
  this.searchIcon = './assets/tabs/search.svg';
  this.notiIcon = './assets/tabs/group.svg';
  this.chatIcon = './assets/tabs/chat.svg';
  this.profIcon = './assets/tabs/user.svg';
}

changeSearchIcon(): void {
  // change user icon
  this.searchIcon = './assets/tabs/clicked-search.svg';

  // reset others icon
  this.newsIcon = './assets/tabs/home.svg';
  this.notiIcon = './assets/tabs/group.svg';
  this.chatIcon = './assets/tabs/chat.svg';
  this.profIcon = './assets/tabs/user.svg';
}

...
```

Appreciate if anyone would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before, I tried to put css color into `ion-tab-button` and `ion-icon` with an ionic icon. The color change as expected, but not with custom icon.

```
<ion-tab-button tab="news/home" style="color: blue">
  <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label class="tab-title">News</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>
```

After a day, I try to check why the custom icon won't change the color if we do like this method. Then I try to check the Ionic SVG icon layers in Adobe Illustrator CC. and there is it.

[image]

As you can see there is `<path>` inside layer 1 (Ionic icon)

[image]

And the problem is my SVG file. To make this work with css properties, I just need to edit the layer.

[image]

[image]

this is the result after editing the layer, work as expected :)

[image]

Solution: You just need to add color css and get the right layer SVG icon

Further, I will update how to use custom icon when the tab is active.

> UPDATE 2:

This is the working html code:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar class="tab-bar" slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="news/home">
      <ion-icon class="icon-news" src="./assets/tabs/md-custom-home.svg"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="tab-title">News</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="search">
      <ion-icon class="icon-search" src="./assets/tabs/md-custom-search.svg"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="tab-title">Search</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="networking">
      <ion-icon class="icon-networking" src="./assets/tabs/md-custom-networking.svg"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label class="tab-title">Networking</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

SCSS:

```
ion-tab-button {
  --color: #000000;
  --color-selected: #00cee5;
}
```

just make sure to use the right SVG ;)

Comment: What worked for me to have to color working was editting the svg file in notepad and making sure there was no 'fill' property set. No editting in AI required.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure that my approach is better, but this could be another way of doing the same thing.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button tab="news/home" (click)="changeNewsIcon()">
        <ion-icon [src]="isNewsSelected ? newsIcon : clickedNewsIcon"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label class="tab-title">News</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
      <ion-tab-button tab="user" (click)="changeSearchIcon()">
        <ion-icon [src]="isSearchSelected ? searchIcon clickedSearchIcon"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label class="tab-title">Search</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

**TypeScript Component:**

```
export class SomeComponent {

  newsIcon = './assets/tabs/home.svg';
  clickedNewsIcon = './assets/tabs/clicked-home.svg';
  searchIcon = './assets/tabs/search.svg';
  clickedSsearchIcon = './assets/tabs/clicked-search.svg';

  isNewsSelected = false;
  isSearchSelected= false;

  changeNewsIcon(): void {    
    resetAll();
    this.isNewsSelected = true;
  }

  changeSearchIcon(): void {
   resetAll();
   this.isSearchSelected = true;
  }

  resetAll(){
    this.isNewsSelected = false;
    this.isSearchSelected= false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good approach :) Other than this method, I also tried edit the color css for ion-icon but its only work with ionic icon but not for custom icon

Comment: This is a workaround.Its not working when you moving from One tab and its sub view and goto another tab at this time selected image is different  and selected tab is different.

Answer (score 0):

**first in html:**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="home" (click)="changeIcon('home')">
      <ion-icon [hidden]="!activeHomepage" name="md-homepage"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon [hidden]="activeHomepage" name="md-homepage-inactive"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label></ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="info" (click)="changeIcon('info')">
      <ion-icon [hidden]="!activeInfo" name="md-info"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon [hidden]="activeInfo" name="md-info-inactive"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label></ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="inbox" (click)="changeIcon('inbox')">
      <ion-icon [hidden]="!activeNotification" name="md-notification"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon [hidden]="activeNotification" name="md-notification-inactive"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label></ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>


    <ion-tab-button tab="profile" (click)="changeIcon('profile')">
      <ion-icon [hidden]="!activeProfile" name="md-profile"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon [hidden]="activeProfile" name="md-profile-inactive"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label></ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**:

```
activeHomepage = false;
  activeInfo = false;
  activeNotification = false;
  activeProfile = false;

  constructor() {
    this.activeHomepage = true;
  }
```

add this function:

```
 changeIcon(page) {
    if (page == 'home') {
      this.activeHomepage = true;
      this.activeProfile = false;
      this.activeNotification = false;
      this.activeInfo = false;
    } else if (page == 'info') {
      this.activeHomepage = false;
      this.activeProfile = false;
      this.activeNotification = false;
      this.activeInfo = true;

    } else if (page == 'inbox') {
      this.activeHomepage = false;
      this.activeProfile = false;
      this.activeNotification = true;
      this.activeInfo = false;
    }
    else {
      this.activeHomepage = false;
      this.activeProfile = true;
      this.activeNotification = false;
      this.activeInfo = false;
    }

  }
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5asz.png)
it's simple and work fine. thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I didn't like none of the solutions explained in here. So I have new one:

Inside the ion-tab-button you place 2 imgs with class names like "normal" and "selected". Like the ion-tab-button will have "tab-selected" class when it is selected, by css will hide and show every image depending on that class.

Example:

html

```
<ion-tab-button tab="products">
    <img class="normal" src="/assets/img/tabs/products.svg" width="30" height="30" />
    <img class="selected" src="/assets/img/tabs/products-selected.svg" width="30" height="30" />
    {{"MENU.PRODUCTS_SHORT" | transloco}}
</ion-tab-button>
```

css

```
ion-tab-button{
    img.normal{
        display: block;
    }
    img.selected{
        display: none;
    }
    &.tab-selected{
        img.normal{
            display: none;
        }
        img.selected{
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this approach is very simple plus avoid problems when the tab is selected without clicking on it.